# Does ISRO's RLV have a future manned spacecraft in mind?

Tags: reuse, isro, launch-vehicle

The Indian Space Research Organization (ISRO) is currently testing a [Reusable Launch Vehicle (RLV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLV_Technology_Demonstration_Programme) in a technology demonstration program. Does this program have a future manned vehicle in mind? Or is it currently planned to stay unmanned?

Maybe there's no clear future goal in mind aside from having a reusable launch vehicle, but I have a hard time imagining that ISRO doesn't have some sort of (tenative, at least) goal in mind for the fruits of this RLV program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ISRO has ambition for a full fledged manned space program, but is actually awaiting the green light from the government.

ISRO's director has clarify their planning on how they would achieve it but in India according to five year planning granted by planning commission they have to wait for year 2017 for the complete clarification of government and granting of budget.

http://www.indianspacestation.com/iss/35-articles/194-indian-space-flight-are-we-there-yet?showall=1&limitstart=

ISRO has manned space exploration planning which are executing in parallel. some are in planning some are in development some are in testing phase.
some of these are

**CARE**

Crew module Atmospheric Reentry Experiment which tested a capsule type vehicle similar to Soyuz, which is I think [what will send the first Indian astronauts from Indian soil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISRO_Orbital_Vehicle).

**GSLV MK3**

And GSLV MK3 is the workforce which is going to send the capsule up to orbit.

http://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/gslv-mk-iii/

**Astronauts**

There is an astronaut programme is also in planning awaiting the government decision.

http://www.dnaindia.com/india/report-indian-space-research-organisation-hunt-on-for-vyomanauts-desi-astronauts-1329928

**Avatar**

This is going to be final phase of RLV experiments.

http://aermech.in/avatar-spacecraftreusable-launch-vehiclefuture-spaceplanedrdoisroindia/

All in all ISRO has planned a manned space program which depends on the political will and need of government.

Although ISRO's motto is different from other space agencies out there.

Comment: I thought AVATAR was unrelated to RLV. Do you have a source for your comment that RLV will culminate in AVATAR?

Comment: Here the thing is the overall tests of rlv-td concept was to create scramjet propulsive craft which is reusable and avatar craft was commisioned by drdo but there are no further planning or whatsoever is going on in the name of avatar, instead rlv-td is going in the same direction to create a final model which is may or may not called as avatar in future. http://aermech.in/avatar-spacecraftreusable-launch-vehiclefuture-spaceplanedrdoisroindia/

Comment: Sounds reasonable enough--I'll upvote.